# automatically display the selected item in jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm done with retrieving data from MySQL to JComboBox.
It worked successfully.

1. Initial
   [image]
2. I choose category "OTHERS" over "INGREDIENTS" then saved it.
   [image]
3. But when I use the search button, the category display INGREDIENTS instead of OTHERS.
   my problem is that I want to display OTHERS (or whatever  category I choose)
   [image]

If this code will retrieve my data in the field:

```
inventCodeField.setText(rs.getString("ItemCode"));
```

How can I retrieve the data I selected from the `JComboBox` without removing the other choices?

Comment: @GagandeepBali no because if the user choose SHIPPED , JCOMBOBOX should display SHIPPED first before the OPEN and IN PROCESS. What the user will choose , it will be display. How can I do it? :)

Comment: I posted my searchbutton code :) the CMBNAME is my JCOMBOBOX FIELD :)

Comment: ("index 0") it says cannot applied to given types, It required INT

Comment: I just saw  cmbname.getSelectedIndex() and just tested it.cmbname.setSelectedIndex(0) doesn't work too.  I deleted my comments thank u :)

Comment: yes. Mine too doesn't work :) I'll just wait until it up. Please invite me again as soon as it works. Thank you for helping a beginner and student like me :)

Comment: Now try again please, I am in the room .:-) Try this [LINk](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/8165/room-for-gagandeep-bali-and-mix)

Comment: I'm in the room again thank u

Answer (score 0):

After querying the specific record, extract the field value for category then use it as a parameter for setSelectedItem() of JComboBox class.

```
// assume that category is a String that holds the category value after querying
cbo_category.setSelectedItem(category);
```